# How to plot one dimensional data with margin of error in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice, plotting

I have some one dimensional classified data from several benchmarks with a margin of error. How can I plot them in LibreOffice Calc 4.3 with error bars?

The data follows this scheme with more entities studied:

```
                    XYZ   TMS   WMTS   UTFGrid
OpenLayers 2        170   172   153    100
                    4.675 4.902 4.0239 2.84
```

The upper row shows the benchmarking results, while the lower one the margin of error calculated from percentage values.

The problem:

The `XY` diagram shows coordinate values on the X axis. I would need something like the `Stock 2` diagram, but without upper and lower values calculated. For representing the margin of error, I would like to use the `Y error bars` function. Also, the records must be represented by points, like in the `XY`, or the `Stock 2` diagram types.

UPDATE:

As the question caused some confusion, here is a graphical representation of the desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution, which uses the `Points Only` line diagram. It needs some tinkering though to look nice. There should be an empty record on the beginning, and on the end of the data range, like on the following picture:

[image]

The range of the `Y error bar` must also follow this template.

The resulting diagram is acceptable, however it falls short of my expectations. As the X axis contains categories, instead of coordinates, the different entities should be rendered besides each other, so one cannot cover out the rest, if the values are nearly equivalent (like in the bars diagram).

I wonder if there is a convenient way to achieve my conception with LibreOffice Calc.